# How to avoid wrong floating-point representation when using R xlsx, readColumns

Tags: r, xlsx

I read data in R by using **xlsx** package **readColumns()**. There are different data types in columns (character and numeric) and so I have to set colClasses = "character".

I use (for example)

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
sheet <- sheets[["Tab1"]]
rows  <- getRows(sheet, rowIndex = 121:126)
cells <- getCells(rows, colIndex = 6:10, simplify = TRUE)

x1 <- readColumns(sheet = sheet, startColumn = 6, endColumn = 10, startRow = 121,
                           endRow = 126, as.data.frame=TRUE, header=FALSE, 
                           colClasses="character",
                           stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and get

```
x1 <- structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L),
                                .Label = c("< 0,0001", "1.0E-4"), class = "factor"),
                 X2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L),
                                .Label = c("< 0,0001", "2.0E-4"), class = "factor"),
                 X3 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L),
                                .Label = c("0.0023", "0.0044", "0.018600000000000002"),
                                class = "factor"),
                 X4 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L),
                                .Label = c("0.0044", "0.006", "0.0213"),
                                class = "factor"), 
                 X5 = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L),
                                .Label = c("0.0019", "0.0031000000000000003", "0.0147"),
                                class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5"),
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are some values like **0.018600000000000002**. In Excel it is just **0.0186**.

When I use

```
x2 <- lapply(cells, getCellValue, keepFormulas=FALSE,
                encoding="UTF-8")
```

I get the following right values, but in a list.

```
x2 <- structure(list(`121.6` = "< 0,0001", `121.7` = "< 0,0001", `121.8` = 0.0186, 
                `121.9` = 0.0213, `121.10` = 0.0147, `122.6` = "< 0,0001", 
                `122.7` = "< 0,0001", `122.8` = 0.0023, `122.9` = 0.006, 
                `122.10` = 0.0019, `123.6` = 1e-04, `123.7` = 2e-04, `123.8` = 0.0044, 
                `123.9` = 0.0044, `123.10` = 0.0031), .Names = c("121.6", 
                                                                 "121.7", "121.8", "121.9", "121.10", "122.6", "122.7", "122.8", 
                                                                 "122.9", "122.10", "123.6", "123.7", "123.8", "123.9", "123.10"
                ))
```

How can I avoid this behavior?